# How to redirect the Perl script output from command issued in windows command prompt to text file

Tags: windows, perl, command-prompt

I am new to Perl and I am executing a .pl file within the CommandPrompt dialog box in Windows 7 by doing the following:

```
c:\perlscripts\runReport.pl 5
```

In addition to seeing the output in the CommandPrompt dialog box is there a way that I can redirect the output to a text file as well?

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you append '> filename.txt' to your line, it will output the results to a file instead. If you want to do both, there is apparently the wintee utility at http://code.google.com/p/wintee/. If it is similar to UNIX tee, than using it should only require you to append '| tee filename.txt' to your line.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I actually tried that but here is the issue.  In the commandprompt dialog box I'm showing a stack trace that is printing out but it does not print to the text file.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: @Melinda It's probably going to STDERR, so you could send both to the same place by appending '2>&1' to the end of your line.

Comment: @Melinda: It's not a dialogue box - it's a window.

Comment: Thanks Borodin.  I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Craig this is what I'm understanding you to say that I execute:
C:\perlscripts>runReport.pl 4 melinda.txt 2>&1
Unfortunately, that did not work.  Thanks.

Comment: The "4" is just a parameter

Comment: I don't think the windows command prompt supports `2>&1`.  You could try wrapping your script in `eval { ... }; print $@;`

Comment: @Melinda, it would actually be 'runReport.pl 4 > melinda.txt 2>&1', but if you are going to use tee like tohava pointed out, it would be 'runReport 4 | tee melinda.txt 2>&1'

Comment: @ysth - works for me, and is mentioned here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930

Comment: Thank u so much. I appreciate all ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the output in command line.
You can write the output in a file.

```
# Opening file to write the program's output. 
open(FH, ">myFile.txt") or die "Cannot open myFile.txt";

# include module to dump output.
use Data::Dumper;
print FH Dumper(@output);

close FH;
```

Else you can write like this:

```
perl my_script.pl > myFile.txt
```

Comment: You should recommend using 3-arg `open` instead of 2-arg. http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html